# Is there a way to make an item in a DropDownList not selectable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have an ASP.net dropdownlist with four items,

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Select Payment Method</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem>Credit Card</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem>PayPal</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem>WeKea Store Gift Card</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Is there a way to make "Select Payment Method" not selectable?  I read through all the properties of an ASP.net DDL and I dont see anything of the sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `disabled` attribute ([see here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp)) and apply it to the `ListItem`:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0" disabled="disabled">Select Payment Method</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Credit Card</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>PayPal</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>WeKea Store Gift Card</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

This will render the option as greyed out and it will not be selectable.  However, the `selected=True` will override that and it will be displayed as selected when the page loads, which I think is what you want.

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  Works exactly as I wanted it to!